# Copying bytes object to shared memory list truncates trailing zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-memory

I'm trying to copy large `bytes` objects into a shareable list that's been initialized with `bytes` objects of large enough size. When the `bytes` object I'm copying over has trailing zeros (i.e. final values are `0x00`), the new entry in the shared memory list is missing these zeros. Zeros in the middle of the data do not cause early truncation. A minimal example is below with the output.

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory as shm

shmList = shm.ShareableList([bytes(50)])
testBytes = bytes.fromhex("00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff0000")

shmList[0] = testBytes
print(testBytes)
print(shmList[0])

shmList.shm.close()
shmList.shm.unlink()
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\x11"3DUfw\x88\x99\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x11"3DUfw\x88\x99\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff'
```

I would expect the `bytes` object would get copied over in full, including the trailing zeros. This seems like a "feature": [sourcecode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d81b4f8ff84311fa737e62f2883442ec06d7d5d8/Lib/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py#L280), but why?

Are there any straightforward workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CPython [seems to](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py#L280) explicitly `.rstrip(b'\x00')`, but there doesn't seem to be any mention of this in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.ShareableList). There is nothing documented at all about the storage neither in terms of semantics nor implementation (except that it should use (or be compatible with) the struct module).

Personally, I'd say the way it is handled currently deserves to be considered a bug. Valid `bytes` objects are allowed to have trailing zero bytes, so the current implementation does not preserve specific valid values where it should do. You could file an issue to CPython about this.

Comment: Tracked in https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/106939

Answer (score 2):

To add to @abel1502's answer, the outcome of this comes from `struct` which is used to pack the data into a buffer

Simplifying a bit, what is done here is basically:

```py
buf = bytearray(10)

original = bytes.fromhex("001100")

struct.pack_from(
    f'6s',
    buf,
    0,
    original
)

(restored,) = struct.unpack_from(
    f'6s',
    buf,
    0
)

print(restored)
```

which unfortunately reveals that unpack_from doesn't respect the format length:

```
restored: b'\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Surprising, despite the format is specifying the length, the entire trailing buffer is still returned (+an extra trailing null!)

I would still argue that ShareableList (since it clearly knows the size/format) should be able to crop the output rather than blindly stripping all trailing nulls it gets from struct.